# Easy way to handle post data in meteor.js?

Tags: javascript, meteor

I need to handle some POST data in my meteor.js app, is there an easy way to do this?

Very basic, if it was a PHP app I would just want the $_POST variable.

Comment: One could argue that it's not best practice to actually do POSTs in a meteor app, at least to your meteor server. If your want to do HTTP request to a remote server have a look here: http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_http

Comment: Yeah, it's an external service that will post data to the app, nothing I can do about that in this case I'm afraid. :( So if it's possible it would be super.

Answer (score 4):

Meteor router

https://github.com/tmeasday/meteor-router#server-side-routing

```
Meteor.Router.add('/items/:id', 'POST', function(id) {
  // update Item Function
  return [200, 'ok'];
});
```

Comment: What I would need though is to access the POST data on the client, is that possible using the meteor router?

Comment: no.. on the client you can only use params and query, no body

Comment: @KristofferK you can use [Meteor.publish()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_publish) and [Meteor.subscribe()](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteor_subscribe) to send POST data from the server to the client.

Answer (score 1):

If you are simply looking to intercept the GET and POST data, then send Meteor on it's merry way, you could do something like this on the server.

```
if (Meteor.isServer) {

  var connect = Npm.require('connect');
  var app = __meteor_bootstrap__.app;
  var post, get;

  app
    // parse the POST data
    .use(connect.bodyParser())
    // parse the GET data
    .use(connect.query())
    // intercept data and send continue
    .use(function(req, res, next) {
      post = req.body;
      get = req.query;
      return next();
    });

  Meteor.startup(function() {
    // do something with post and get variables
  });

}
```

**EDIT 11/01/13**

I ended up creating a smart package for this (for myself). There is no documentation but you are welcome to use it. https://github.com/johnnyfreeman/request-data

To retrieve the `foo` request variable:

```
RequestData.get('foo') // --> 'bar'
RequestData.post('foo') // --> 'bar'
```

Both methods will `throw` a `Meteor.Error` if the key isn't found so make sure you use wrap with a `try`/`catch` if the variable is optional.

Comment: for others trying this, 'connect' isn't included in Meteor, you'll need to install via NPM or try the custom package (which looks like it installs)

Answer (score 1):

I'm using this package to serialize body data: `simple:json-routes`. Here is [the link.](https://atmospherejs.com/simple/json-routes)

And this code snippet to access it:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use('/api/request', (req, res, next) => {
    console.log(req.body);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Meteor's `Iron Router`, [docs here](https://github.com/iron-meteor/iron-router), since `Router` (as mentioned above) is outdated and might be no longer functional.

```
Router.route('/items/:id', {where: 'server'})
    .get(function () {
        this.response.end('get request\n');
    })
    .post(function () {
        this.response.end('post request\n');
    });
```