# Can Meteor's Backbone Router handle POST requests?

Tags: post, backbone.js, meteor

I have a Meteor app which uses a router as per the sample [Todos app](https://www.meteor.com/examples/todos), eg.:

```
var TodosRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
  routes: {
    ":list_id": "main"
  },
  main: function (list_id) {
    ...
  },
  ...
});

Router = new TodosRouter;
```

I have an external service that lets me know when it is finished via a POST request to a URL that I specify.  On receiving the POST request, it needs to perform some functions.  Can I set this up consistent with the above framework?  If not, am I better off writing a separate non-Meteor (eg. nodejs) app to handle the POSTs, or is there a way to make it work within Meteor?

I know [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683787/easy-way-to-handle-post-data-in-meteor-js), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11799079/how-do-i-access-request-parameters-in-meteor) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15059125/how-to-serve-http-requests-over-meteor) StackOverflow question are similar, but none of the answers explains how to do it with the `Backbone.Router`.

Thanks!

Comment: isn't `backbone` a client-only router? If so, then the answer is no.

Comment: you can use `iron-router` to handle POST requests as described in this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943084/is-it-possible-to-define-iron-router-server-side-routes-that-respond-to-certain/20943328#20943328

Comment: Thanks. I've been hesitating to use `Iron-Router` because it seems like a big addition for what seems like a simple problem. And I wasn't clear on how to combine it with the `Backbone.Router`. But I've got it working now with some modifications. I'll write up a short answer to describe it better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I migrated from the `Backbone.Router` to `Iron-Router`. I couldn't see a way to use them both at once.

First, I put code like in @Christian Fritz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20943084/is-it-possible-to-define-iron-router-server-side-routes-that-respond-to-certain/20943328#20943328), in the `server` folder:

```
Router.map(function () {
    this.route('foo', {
        path: '/foo',
        where: 'server',
        action: function() {
            if (this.request.method == 'POST') {
                console.log('post request received');
            } else {
                this.response.writeHead(404);
            }
        }
    })
});
```

That handles the `POST` request, as tested by including a `console.log` in the `action` (which will write to the terminal window where `meteor` is running), and typing:

```
curl --data "p=bar" localhost:3000/foo
```

Then I replaced the `Backbone.Router` call with code in the `client` folder, as described in the [Iron-Router docs](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router), eg.

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function () {
    this.route('home', {
        path: '/',
        template: 'homepage',
    });
});
```

Then I had to rewrite my templates so that pages were generated from different templates, instead of from different `Session` variable settings. This actually simplified my code, eg. instead of:

```
<body>
    {{#if onPage 'home'}}
        {{> homepage }}
    {{/if}}
    {{#if onPage 'help'}}
        {{> helppage }}
    {{/if}}
    ...
</body>
```

and

```
UI.registerHelper("onPage", function(name) { 
    return Session.equals('page', name);
});
```

it's just:

```
<template name="layout">
    {{>yield}}
</template>
```

Any javascript that needs to direct the user to a specific page uses `Router.go()` with the route name:

```
Router.go('home');
```

Beyond that, I found a few places where I used to be able to assume my collections `.findOne()` had found one, but seem to have broken with Iron-Router. Wrapping these in `if`s fixed them.

In Meteor 0.8, to check what page you are on you can use ([see here](https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/issues/533)):

```
Router.current().lookupProperty('template')
```