# How do I setup meteor to receive events from an external API?

Tags: meteor

I have registered my web address (let's just call it `https://mywebaddress/callbacks`) with this external API and it will now send me JSON when it completes an action. I don't need to initiate anything outbound to it, I just need to receive the JSON and store it.

EDIT: 
JSON data will be receive via POST

Comment: how will the JSON be sent? http POST?

Comment: There's this answer, but it is old: [easy way to handle post data in meteor js](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14683787/easy-way-to-handle-post-data-in-meteor-js)

Comment: This also looks interesting: http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API

Comment: This question can be improved by being more specific about how the data will be sent (http POST? PUT?), a link to the API if it is public, and details of what happens if you simply use one of the methods for creating an API listed above in in meteorpedia. Would a REST API for your app work? Can the data transmitter be told to use an api token for security?

Comment: JSON data will receive via POST

Comment: I'm using balanced payments https://docs.balancedpayments.com/1.1/overview/

I just need to get the events from this payment processor and record them in meteor so that I know if the donation that was submitted has been completed and if not, what the error was.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Paul's link sent me in the right direction. (http://www.meteorpedia.com/read/REST_API).

Then I found the section titled "WebApp.connectHandlers and connect".

I used the code found there, but in my instance there was an error in the code. I had to change the first line from `var connect = Npm.require('connect');` to `var connect = Meteor.require('connect');`

Here is the code below.

```
// necessary to parse POST data
var connect = Meteor.require('connect');
// necessary for Collection use and other wrapped methods
var Fiber = Npm.require('fibers');
WebApp.connectHandlers
    .use(connect.urlencoded())  // these two replace
    .use(connect.json())        // the old bodyParser
    .use('/getUserProfile', function(req, res, next) {

        // necessary for Collection use and other wrapped methods
        Fiber(function() {

            var userId = req.body.userId;
            var user = Meteor.users.findOne(userId);

            res.writeHead(200, {'Content-Type': 'application/json'});
            res.end(JSON.stringify(user.profile));

        }).run();
    });    
}
```

Then to test that this was working I used http://www.hurl.it/. I changed the destination to POST and added a header of content-type - application/json. I then pasted in the body some JSON that I knew came from balanced. If you need a tool to see what is actually being posted to your server you can use http://requestb.in/.