# How do I access HTTP POST body (form-data) with Meteor's WebApp? Or anything else?

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, iron-router

I already tried server-routing with Iron Router, but that doesn't work. Then I discovered WebApp, which seems like it's supposed to handle this.

But when I inspect the req object:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/api/add", function( req, res, next ) {
    console.log( req );
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world from: " + Meteor.release);
});
```

I don't see any of my POST form-data. There's no body property, and I don't see the data itself anywhere under any other property.

How can I access this data? I'm going crazy trying to figure out something I thought would be relatively simple...

Answer (score 10):

Yeah, I had the same issue.  With connect, the post body isn't automatically in the request object.  You can use middleware like this https://stackoverflow.com/a/24122700/5203563 or get it yourself like this:

```
WebApp.connectHandlers.use("/api/add", function( req, res, next ) {

  var body = "";
  req.on('data', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function (data) {
    body += data;
  }));

  req.on('end', Meteor.bindEnvironment(function () {
    console.log(body);
    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end("Hello world from: " + Meteor.release);
  }));
});
```

Comment: Heck yeah dude thanks!